# Ethereum Mobile Wallets

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I've set up an Ethereum private blockchain on AWS by using MetaMask with two wallets I can send/receive ether between two wallets without any issues.

This means the private network is working fine. Now I want to demo the private blockchain to some colleagues. But demoing it using the Metamask browser plugin is not simulating a real-world scenario.

So I want to initiate a new transaction on that private blockchain using a mobile device.

Is there any Android Ethereum wallet application (maybe an implementation of Ethereum Light Client) that can connect to any private Ethereum blockchain?

Comment: The walleth is allowing users to connect to the test networks, but it's not allowing to connect to any private blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use go-ethereum's builtin mobile framework, for more info see: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/dapp/mobile

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can code any JavaScript wallet and open it inside a web view.

I recommend LightWallet as a JavaScript wallet: 
https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet

Inside your JS code, you have to use a web3Provider. For your private network, you have to set the host to a running RPC node.

Sample code from [github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/master/example/example_demo_video.html](http://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/master/example/example_demo_video.html):

```
    var web3Provider = new HookedWeb3Provider({
      host: "http://104.236.65.136:8545",
      transaction_signer: keystore
    });
```

You can also consider building a native mobile wallet. Depending on something like: https://github.com/walleth/walleth. But for demonstration purpose, a web view could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.myetherwallet.com/ in your mobile browser, and connect to your private network using custom network option of myEtherWallet.